# How to set different layouts for different fragments which is embedded inside a tab view in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm currently trying to create a tabView where each tab opens a different layout. I'm using android.support.design.widget.TabLayout and I successfully linked it with pagerView using an adapter. Now inside myFragment class if I call onCreateView and inflate a layout, the layout (fragment_main) is displayed in all tabs.

```
public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {
        public MyFragment() {

        }

        public static MyFragment newInstance(int pageNumber) {
            MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
            return myFragment;
        }


        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,false);

            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

I have 3 fragments connecting 3 tabs. Now how to set different layout for each fragment.

My adapter class is

```
class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        String[] tabs;
        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            tabs=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            NavigationActivity.MyFragment myFragment = NavigationActivity.MyFragment.newInstance(position);
            return myFragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return tabs[position];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Create 3 Fragments (subclasses) and 3 layouts (xml) files

Comment: @MuhammadBabar could you give a code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `getItem()` method write,

```
Fragment frgmt = null;

    switch (position) {
    case 0:

        frgmt = new fragment1(Context);
        break;
    case 1:

        frgmt = new fragment2(Context);
        break;
    case 2:

        frgmt = new fragment3(Context);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return frgmt;
```

Then create these fragment and their respective layouts.

Comment: It has to be write in your adapter class

Comment: @lijo050, U are Welcome

Answer (score 2):

You are passing same fragment for all the position in the below method, which is causing the problem,

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        NavigationActivity.MyFragment myFragment = NavigationActivity.MyFragment.newInstance(position);
        return myFragment;
    }
```

For solution you have to return different Fragments for different position or at least with different layout.

```
ArrayList< Fragment > tabFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
fragments.add(new FragmentA());
fragments.add(new FragmentB());
fragments.add(new FragmentC());


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return tabFragments.get(position);
}
```

Again,

I found the below mentioned blog as very useful. Each steps is described there. It is using TabListener. If the implementation is not certainly the same which you are looking for but you may get a good overview,

Android Fragment Tabs Example:
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/app/fragment/android-fragment-tabs-example/

Answer (score 0):

please go to this i think this could help you out---- https://codeload.github.com/culmor30/android-fragments-example/zip/master